# How to auto scroll (up&down) to section when user scroll (not click!)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to achieve a sliding scroll (like [fullPage.js](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)) by myself. I don't want to create a plugin either use a plugin. I only want to scroll/slide to a section when user trigger scroll (up and down!).

I've searched all over the internet and I do not know how to prevent the user from scrolling to replace standard scroll behavior by my animated scroll (desktop and mobile). I want to implement this animation inside a Bootstrap carousel item.

**Summarizing, I have a carousel with several items, and each item will have a caption (outside the viewport). When the user scrolls down, then I will show the caption (like third slide [here](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/autoHeight.html)), and when the user scrolls up, I will scroll up and hide the caption.**

[image: slide behaviour]

Here is the CodePen with the carousel example running: [link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zgONVj)

This is what I get so far (I've got part of the code from StackOverflow)...

```
$(function(){
    var _top = $(window).scrollTop();
    var _direction;
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var _cur_top = $(window).scrollTop();
        if(_top < _cur_top)
        {
            _direction = 'down';
            window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
        } else {
            _direction = 'up';
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        }
        _top = _cur_top;
        console.log(_direction);
    });
});
```

I get a very (very!) slow animation... It is not smooth at all.

I've tried this too:

```
$(document.body).on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || event.originalEvent.detail < 0) {
        // Scroll up
        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 400);
    }
    else {
        // Scroll down
    }

});
```

But, that code does not work and I get this error: **[Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to the target being treated as passive.**

I will be very thankful if you can help me, please!

## **Edited:**

Someone helped me at "StackOverflow en español". Here is the [solution](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/279554/forzar-scroll-hasta-el-final-principio-de-la-p%C3%A1gina-cuando-el-usuario-hace-scrol)!! Many thanks to @matahombres ;)

Comment: Your listener is passive, so you cannot call `preventDefault`. The error literally explains itself.

Comment: ok, thanks. What can I do then?

Comment: I don't understand why you don't want to use the plugin, when you're already using one? You don't need jQuery to achieve this but it helps - that is the same with fullpage.js - you don't need it, but it helps.

Comment: Hi @Kobe, first of all, I would like to improve my coding skills (I'm really bad at jQuery and JS). I've tried to use fullPage.js but the plugin does not fit with my needs. I know the plugin can slide right/left and up/down, but the plugin's main direction is up/down, not right/left (if I'm right). I've tried to use Bootstrap's carousel and fullPage.js to achieve my goal, but I couldn't... So here I am, asking for some help.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend trying to build something so complex if you don't understand the error you were receiving. Maybe try making your own carousel, then making your own scroll, then try combining the two, rather than going into it without a solid understanding of javascript. Getting answers here will solve your problem, but it will not improve your understanding.

Comment: Okay, then there's no help ... thanks! If I understood the errors and knew how to create the carousel and scroll by myself, I would not be asking for help, do not you think?

Comment: I didn't say not to ask for help, but rather to learn basics before diving into something so complicated. Sure asking here will give you immediate answers, but you it'll be aged to modify that code

Comment: Kobe, here is the solution another user has given to me. I do not know if it is the best one, but it works! [link (in spanish)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/279554/forzar-scroll-hasta-el-final-principio-de-la-p%c3%a1gina-cuando-el-usuario-hace-scrol). CodePen updated with solution.